# Blender to Unity 5: Animations with many rigs

Tags: blender, unity-game-engine

I have a model that is rigged and also a weapon that is rigged. The rig of the weapon is connected to the model's hand so that it moves accordingly (I connected it with CNTRL+P > Set parent to bone). I then made the animations for the model and then the bow and combined them using the NLA editor. The problem is, when I use the .blend file in Unity 5, the weapon doesn't move, only the model. Am I joining the two incorrectly or am I just using the NLA editor wrong? Thanks.

Edit: I don't actually save anything in the NLA editor because I assumed you didn't have to (and I don't see any save button xD). I'm very confused as to how I'm supposed to get whatever I just made into something I can use in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my daily basis, I just create an animation for character, and in Unity I am parent a weapon to the, for example, hand bone. This simple approach works fine for me. And try exporting your model as .fbx, usually its better.

Comment: I've come to realise this yes. It's less complicated that it seems you just have to synchronize the animation though (I have a bow that I want to stretch during the animation). Do you know if it's easier/more convenient in other CG programs (maya,etc)?